# impresion directa desde fpdf

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, wampserver

cabe recalcar que estoy trabajando con funciones y no con clases por ende
no tengo idea de como incorporar el siguiente tutorial a mi trabajo
https://sistemasumma.com/2012/01/28/impresion-automatica-de-tiquet-con-fpdf/

ya tengo una plantilla creada en la libreria de fpdf que ya esta funcionando
el cual es el siguiente codigo.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Venta;
use Codedge\Fpdf\Fpdf\Fpdf;
Use App\Producto;
use App\DetalleVenta;
use DB;


class VentaController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        return $productos=Producto::all();

    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $r)
    {
        //Seccion del manejo de la venta
        //return $r;

         $venta = new Venta;

        $venta->folio=$r->get('folio');
        $venta->fecha_venta=$r->get('fecha_venta');
        $venta->num_articulos=$r->get('num_articulos');
        $venta->subtotal=$r->get('subtotal');
        $venta->iva=$r->get('iva');
        $venta->total=$r->get('total');
        $venta->guia=$r->get('guia');
        $venta->Propina=$r->get('Propina');
        $venta->comicion=$r->get('comicion');

        $venta->save();

        //Fin de manejo de la ventas

        //Obtenemos del Request el json de los detalles
        $detalles = $r->get('detalles');

        //Insertamos los detalles a la tabla detalle_vemtas
        DetalleVenta::insert($detalles);
        //Dinero_Venta::insert($detalles2);
        //Actualizamos el estado de los inventarios
        for ($i=0; $i < count($detalles); $i++) { 

            $cantidadVendida=$detalles[$i]['cantidad'];
            $productoVendido=$detalles[$i]['sku'];

            DB::update("UPDATE productos
                SET cantidad=cantidad-$cantidadVendida
                WHERE sku=$productoVendido");

           
        }
        
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
        return $venta=Venta::find($id);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
    public function ticket($folio){
        $venta= Venta::find($folio);
        $altura = 100;

       //Definimos el tamaño del ticket
       $pdf = new Fpdf('P', 'mm', array(58,$altura ));

       $pdf->AddPage();

      $pdf->SetMargins(3,2,3);
       $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 6);
       $pdf->Cell(31,3,'HOTEL Y RESTAURANTE ',0,1,'C');
       $pdf->Cell(15,3,'',0,0,'C');
       $pdf->Cell(15,3,'SANTA MARIA',0,1,'C');
       $pdf->Cell(8,3, 'FOLIO:', 0,0,'L');
       $pdf->Cell(20,3, $venta->folio,0,1,'L');
       $pdf->Cell(10,3, 'FECHA:',0,0,'L');
       $pdf->Cell(10,3, $venta->fecha_venta, 0,1,'L');
       $pdf->Cell(40,1,'','B','C');
       $pdf->Ln(2);
       $ancho=13;
       $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 5);
       $pdf->Cell(5,3, 'SKU',1,0,'C');
       $pdf->Cell($ancho,3, 'PRODUTO',1,0,'C');
       $pdf->Cell(8,3, 'CANT',1,0,'C');
       $pdf->Cell(5,3, 'P.U',1,0,'C');
       $pdf->Cell(8,3,'TOTAL',1,1,'C');

       $detalles=$venta->detalles;
        $ancho=15;
       foreach ($detalles as $detalle) {
            $pdf->Cell(5,3,$detalle->sku,0,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell($ancho,3,$detalle->productos->nombre,0,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(8,3,$detalle->cantidad,0,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(5,3,$detalle->precio,0,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(8,3,$detalle->total,0,1,'C');
       }
       $ancho=20;
       $pdf->Cell($ancho,3,'',0,0,'C');
       $pdf->Cell(10,3, 'SUBTOTAL',1,0,'C');
       $pdf->Cell(10,3,$venta->subtotal,1,1,'C');
       /*$pdf->Cell($ancho,3,'',0,0,'C');
       $pdf->Cell(10,3,'IVA',1,0,'C');
       $pdf->Cell(10,3,$venta->iva,1,1,'C');*/
       $pdf->Cell($ancho,3,'',0,0,'C');
       $pdf->Cell(10,3,'PROPINA',1,0,'C');
       $pdf->Cell(10,3,$venta->Propina,1,1,'C');
       $pdf->Cell($ancho,3,'',0,0,'C');
       $pdf->Cell(10,3, 'TOTAL',1,0,'C');
       $pdf->Cell(10,3,$venta->total,1,1,'C');
       $pdf->Ln(2);
    
       $pdf->OutPut();
       exit;
    }
}
```

el cual funciona de maravilla el cual me devuelve el siguiente pdf
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a lo que viene mi pregunta es como lo puedo **imprimir de manera directa** **sin pasar por el cuadro de dialogo he imprimirlo directo**
ya que como es un punto de ventas lo mas optimo es que imprima directo
ya he visto en otros foros que se puede hacer modificando el fpdf pero sus links de ejemplos estan caidos de asi mismo no poder encontrar otra alternativa

este es mi boton para cobrar y posteriormente abrir el pdf en una ventana aparte
pero lo que quiero no es abrirlo en otra pagina, asu vez **quiero imprimirlo directamente**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="vender()" @click="dinero(@{{folio}})">Vender</button>
```

y este es la vista en donde se encuentra el boton
al momento de presionar vender se ejecuta el codigo del boton
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
este es el fragmento del js en donde se hace la acción de vender y llamar el pdf

```
vender:function(){
            var unaVenta = {};
            var deta = [];
            
            //Preparamos un JSON con los detalles 
            for (var i = 0; i < this.ventas.length; i++) {
            deta.push(
                    {   sku:this.ventas[i].sku,
                        folio:this.folio,
                        nombre:this.ventas[i].nombre,
                        cantidad:this.ventas[i].cantidad,
                        precio:this.ventas[i].precio,
                        total:this.ventas[i].total,
                        id_comida:this.ventas[i].id_comida,
                        totalcomision:this.ventas[i].totalcomicion
                    }
                    );
            }
 
            //Find a JSON Detalles
            unaVenta = {
                folio:this.folio,
                fecha_venta:moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                num_articulos:this.noArticulos,
                subtotal:this.subTotal,
                iva:this.iva,
                total:this.granTotal,
                detalles:deta,
                guia:this.nombre_guia,
                Propina:this.propinaTotal,
                comicion:this.comisionTotal,

            };
            console.log(unaVenta);
            //console.log(unaVenta);
            this.$http.post(apiVenta,unaVenta).then(function(j){
                console.log(j);
                $('#modalCobro').modal('hide');
                this.foliar();
                this.ventas=[];
                this.cantidades=[];
            });
            window.open(ruta + '/ticket/' + this.folio,'_blank');
        },
```

para mas detalles dejo el codigo completo de la vista que estoy usando
que es el siguiente

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('titulo','Interface de ventas')
@push('css')

@endpush
@section('contenido')
    
<div id="apiVenta">
<div class="container"><!--INICIO DE CONTAINER-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Escriba el codigo del producto" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" v-model="sku"
                        v-on:keyup.enter="buscarProducto()">

                    <div class="input-group-append">
                         <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" @click="buscarProducto()">Buscar</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" @click="mostrarCobro">Cobrar</button>
                    </div>
                      <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-info" @click="mostrarProducto">Buscar por nombre</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
                
    

                <!-- <h1>@{{prueba}}</h1> -->

            </div>
    </div>
    <!--fin de la cabeza--><!--fin de container-->
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                     <!--p v-bind:algin-->
                    <p id="textArea"><h3>FOLIO: @{{folio}}</h3></p> <!--Es una interpolacion-->
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <select class="form-control" name="nombre" v-model="nombre_guia" placeholder="Elija el tipo de producto">
                            <option value='' selected="true">Seleccione un guia de turistas</option>
                            <option v-for="guias in filtroGuias" ><td>@{{guias.nombre}}</td></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <!--inicio tabla-->
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <th style="background: #FFFF00">CODIGO</th>
                            <th style="background: #FFFF00">PRODUCTO</th>
                            <th style="background: #FFFF00">TIPO</th>
                            <th style="background: #FFFF00" hidden="">comision POR PLATO</th>
                            <th style="background: #FFFF00">OPER.</th>
                            <th style="background: #FFFF00">PRECIO</th>
                            <th style="background: #FFFF00">CANTIDAD</th>
                            <th style="background: #FFFF00">TOTAL</th>
                            <th style="background: #FFFF00" hidden="">TOTAL COMISION</th>
                        </thead> 

                        <tbody>
                            
                            <tr v-for="(venta,index) in ventas">
                                <td>@{{venta.sku}}</td>
                                <td>@{{venta.nombre}}</td>
                                <td>@{{venta.id_comida}}</td>
                                <td hidden="">@{{venta.comicion}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" >
                                        <i class="fas fa-trash" @click="eliminarProducto(index)"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                                <td >@{{venta.precio}}</td>
                                <td><input type="number" v-model.number="cantidades[index]" min="1"></td>
                                <td>@{{totalProducto(index)}}</td>
                                <td hidden="">@{{comicion(index)}}</td>
                                </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table><!--fin tabla-->
                    <hr>
                    @{{ventas}}
                </div>

            </div>
            <!--  FIN DEL ROW  -->
    </div> 
    <!-- FIN DEL CARD BODY -->
</div>
<!-- FIN DEL CARD -->


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8"></div>
    

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="background: #FFFF00">Subtotal</th>
                            <td>$ @{{subTotal}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="background: #FFFF00">PROPINA POR PORCENTAJE</th>
                            <!--<td><b>$ @{{granTotal}}</b></td>-->
                    <td><b>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="porcentaje">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" disabled :value="propina2">
                    </b></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th style="background: #FFFF00">PROPINA</th>
                            <!--<td><b>$ @{{granTotal}}</b></td>-->
                            <td><b><input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="propina"></b></td>
                        </tr>
                         <tr>
                            <th style="background: #FFFF00">Propina Total</th>
                            <td><b>$ @{{propinaTotal}}</b></td>
                        </tr>
                         <tr>
                            <th style="background: #FFFF00">Comision al guia</th>
                            <td><b>@{{comisionTotal}}</b></td>
                                      
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="background: #FFFF00">TOTAL</th>
                            <td><b>$ @{{granTotal}}</b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="background: #FFFF00">Articulos :</th>
                            <td>@{{noArticulos}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    
                
            </div>
            <!-- FIN DEL CARD BODY -->
        </div> 
        <!-- FIN DEL CARD -->
        </div>
            <!-- FIN DEL COL-MD-4 -->
    </div>
</div><!--FIN DE CONTAINER Y DE CLASS ROW-->

<!-- Modal para el formulario del registro de los moovimientos -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalCobro" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Asistente de cobro</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>A PAGAR :</label>    
                </div> 
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" disabled :value="granTotal">
                </div>
            </div><br>

            <div class="form-wor">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>PAGA CON:</label>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="pagara_con">
                </div><br>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label>SU CAMBIO ES: </label>       
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" disabled :value="cambio"> 
                    </div>  
                </div>
                
            </div> 
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      <p id="textArea"><h3>@{{folio}}</h3></p> <!--Es una interpolacion-->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="vender()" @click="dinero(@{{folio}})">Vender</button>
       <!--/* <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="ticket/2022042289043" class="nav-link active">
                  <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>imprimir ticket</p>
                </a>
              </li>*/-->
              
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- aqui termina el modal-->




<!-- Modal para buscar productos -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalProducto" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Buscar_Producto</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
        <form>
            <div><!--tabla2-->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Escriba el nombre del producto" class="form-control" v-model="buscar">
                        </div>
            <!--inicio tabla-->
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <th hidden="" style="background: #FFFF00">SKU</th>
                            <th style="background: #FFFF00">PRODUCTO</th>
                            <th style="background: #FFFF00">PRECIO</th>
                            <th style="background: #FFFF00">AÑADIR A LA VENTA</th>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody max=10 width="50" height="60" >
                        <tr v-for="(producto,index) in filtroProducto">
                            <td hidden="">@{{producto.sku}}</td>
                            <td>@{{producto.nombre}}</td>
                            <td> $@{{producto.precio}}</td>
                            <div>
                                <!--quiero pasar el valor del @{{producto.sku}} a la variable
                                    v-model="sku" pero no se como 
                                    para que en buscar producto me añada un producto
                                    a la venta
                                    estoy usando apiVenta.js-->

                            <td><span class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                        @click="aniadirProducto(producto.sku)">
                            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                        </span></td></div>

                        <!--<button class="btn btn-sm" @click="editandoMascota(mascota.id_mascota)">
                                    <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
                                </button>-->
                        <!--<td><input type="number" v-model.number="cantidades[index]" min="1"></td>-->
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table><!--fin tabla-->
                </div><!--fin tabla2-->

        </form>
        
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Seguir Vendiendo</button>
         <button class="btn btn-success" @click="mostrarCobro" data-dismiss="modal">Cobrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- aqui termina el modal-->
<!-- PLANTILLA MODAL LIMPIO -->






</div><!--Fin de vue-->

    
@endsection

@push('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vue-resource.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/apis/apiVenta.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/apis/apiProducto.js"></script>

    

@endpush


<input type="hidden" name="route" value="{{url('/')}}">
```

y este es el codigo completo del js

```
function init() {

var apiProducto=ruta + '/apiProducto'; //se crea para tener un acceso global. 
var apiVenta=ruta + '/apiVenta';
var apiGuia=ruta + '/apiGuia';
 
new Vue({
    //Asignamos el token
    http: {
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('value')
            }
        },

    //Especificar la zona de actuación de Vue
    el:"#apiVenta",

    //Esta sección de VUE sirve para declarar Variables
    //Y constantes. g
    data:{
        //mensaje: 'HOLA MUNDO DESDE LA UTC',
        sku:'',
        ventas:[],
        productos:[],
        cantidades:[],
        //guias
        guias:[],
        nombre:'',
        celular:'',
        nombre_guia:'Sin Guia',
        //fin de guias
        cant:1,
        auxSubTotal:0,
        pagara_con:0,
        folio:'',
        buscar:'',
        propina:0,
        propina3:0,
        porcentaje:0,




        
    },

    created:function(){
        this.foliar();
        this.obtenerProductos();
        this.obtenerGuias();
    },

    //INICIO DE METHODS
    methods:{
        //obtner datos
            obtenerProductos:function(){
                
                this.$http.get(apiProducto).then(function(json){
                    this.productos=json.data;
                    console.log(json.data);
                }).catch(function(json){
                    console.log(json);
                });
            },//Fin de obtener productos
            obtenerGuias:function(){
            
                this.$http.get(apiGuia).then(function(json){
                    this.guias=json.data;
                    console.log(this.guias);
                }).catch(function(json){
                    console.log(json);
                });
            },//fin de obtener guias
        //fin de obtener datos

        buscarProducto:function(sku){
            var encontrado=0;

            if(this.sku){//INICIO DE IF(THIS.SKU)
    
            var producto = {};

            //Rutina de busqueda

            for (var i = 0; i < this.ventas.length; i++) {

                if (this.sku==this.ventas[i].sku){

                    encontrado=1;
                    this.ventas[i].cantidad++;
                    this.cantidades[i]++;
                    this.sku='';
                    break;
                } //this.ventas[1];

            }//fin de rutina de busqueda

            //Inicio GET de ARRAY
            //var producto = {}
            if (encontrado===0) 
            this.$http.get(apiProducto + '/' + this.sku).then(function(j){
                console.log(j.data);

                producto = {
                    sku:j.data.sku,
                    nombre:j.data.nombre,
                    precio:j.data.precio,
                    id_comida:j.data.id_comida.tipo,
                    comicion:j.data.id_comida.precio,
                    cantidad:1, 
                    total:j.data.precio,
                    foto:'prods/' + j.data.foto,
                };


                this.ventas.push(producto);
                console.log(producto);
                console.log(this.ventas);
                    this.cantidades.push(1);
                this.sku='';
            });
            
        }//FIN DE IF(THIS.SKU)
        console.log(this.ventas);
        },//fin de buscar producto
        aniadirProducto:function(id){
            var encontrado=0;
            this.sku=id;

            if(this.sku){//INICIO DE IF(THIS.SKU)
    
            var producto = {};

            //Rutina de busqueda

            for (var i = 0; i < this.ventas.length; i++) {

                if (this.sku==this.ventas[i].sku){

                    encontrado=1;
                    this.ventas[i].cantidad++;
                    this.cantidades[i]++;
                    this.sku='';
                    break;
                } //this.ventas[1];

            }//fin de rutina de busqueda
            
            if (encontrado===0)
            
            this.$http.get(apiProducto + '/' +this.sku).then(function(j){
                console.log(j.data);

                producto = {
                    sku:j.data.sku,
                    nombre:j.data.nombre,
                    precio:j.data.precio,
                    id_comida:j.data.id_comida.tipo,
                    comicion:j.data.id_comida.precio,
                    cantidad:1, 
                    total:j.data.precio,
                    foto:'prods/' + j.data.foto,
                };

    
                    this.ventas.push(producto);
                    this.cantidades.push(1);
                this.sku='';
            });
        }
        },//fin aniadir producto

        eliminarProducto:function(id){
            this.ventas.splice(id,1); //Splice es eliminar la mascota
        },
        //modales mostrar
        mostrarCobro:function(){
            $('#modalCobro').modal('show');
        },
        mostrarProducto:function(){
            $('#modalProducto').modal('show');
        },
        mostrarticket(){

            $('#modalticket').modal('show');
        },
    
        //fin modales mostrar

        foliar:function(){
            //this.folio="VNT-" + moment().format('YYYYMMD8HMMS');
            this.folio=moment().format('YYYYMMD8HMMS');


        },
        
    
        vender:function(){
            var unaVenta = {};
            var deta = [];
            
            //Preparamos un JSON con los detalles 
            for (var i = 0; i < this.ventas.length; i++) {
            deta.push(
                    {   sku:this.ventas[i].sku,
                        folio:this.folio,
                        nombre:this.ventas[i].nombre,
                        cantidad:this.ventas[i].cantidad,
                        precio:this.ventas[i].precio,
                        total:this.ventas[i].total,
                        id_comida:this.ventas[i].id_comida,
                        totalcomision:this.ventas[i].totalcomicion
                    }
                    );
            }
 
            //Find a JSON Detalles
            unaVenta = {
                folio:this.folio,
                fecha_venta:moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                num_articulos:this.noArticulos,
                subtotal:this.subTotal,
                iva:this.iva,
                total:this.granTotal,
                detalles:deta,
                guia:this.nombre_guia,
                Propina:this.propinaTotal,
                comicion:this.comisionTotal,

            };
            console.log(unaVenta);
            //console.log(unaVenta);
            this.$http.post(apiVenta,unaVenta).then(function(j){
                console.log(j);
                $('#modalCobro').modal('hide');
                this.foliar();
                this.ventas=[];
                this.cantidades=[];
            });
            window.open(ruta + '/ticket/' + this.folio,'_blank');
        },

},
//FIN DE METHODS

//SECCION PARA CALCULAR UN VALOR
computed:{
    totalProducto(){
        return (id)=>{
            var total = 0;
                total=this.ventas[id].precio*this.cantidades[id];

            //ACTUALIZO EL TOTAL DEL PRODUCTIO EN EL ARRAY VENTAS
            this.ventas[id].total=total;

            //ACTUALIZO LA CANTIDAD EN EL ARRAY VENTAS
            this.ventas[id].cantidad=this.cantidades[id];

            return total.toFixed(1);//Regresa ek total con un decimal

        }
    },//FIN DE TOTALPRODUCTO
    comicion(){
        return (id)=>{
            var total1 = 0;
                total1=this.ventas[id].comicion*this.cantidades[id];
                //ACTUALIZO EL TOTAL DEL PRODUCTO EN EL ARRAY VENTAS
                this.ventas[id].totalcomicion=total1;
                
            return total1.toFixed(1);//Regresa ek total con un decimal

        }
    },
    comisionTotal(){
        var total=0;
        var auxSubTotal=0;

        //Se recorre del ultimo hacia abajo
        for (var i = this.ventas.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            total=total+(this.ventas[i].comicion*this.ventas[i].cantidad);
            
        }
        console.log(total);
        //Mando una copia del subtotal a la seccion del data 
        //Para el uso de otros calculos
        auxSubTotal=total.toFixed(1);
        return auxSubTotal;

    },

    subTotal(){
        var total=0;

        //Se recorre del ultimo hacia abajo
        for (var i = this.ventas.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            total=total+this.ventas[i].total;
        }

        //Mando una copia del subtotal a la seccion del data 
        //Para el uso de otros calculos
        this.auxSubTotal=total.toFixed(1);
        return total.toFixed(1);
    },//FIN DEL SUBTOTAL

    iva(){
        var auxIva=0;

        auxIva = this.auxSubTotal*0.16;
        return auxIva.toFixed(1);
    },
        

    granTotal(){
        
        var auxTotal=0;
        var prop=0;
    
        
        auxTotal=Number(this.auxSubTotal)+Number(this.propina)+Number(this.propina2);
        auxTotal=auxTotal;
        //linea 212 cuando la activo dice
        //toFixed no es una funcion 
        //auxTotal=auxTotal+this.propina2;
        // auxTotal=auxTotal.toFixed(1);
        return auxTotal;
    },
    propinaTotal(){
        var propinaTotal = 0;
        propinaTotal=Number(this.propina2)+Number(this.propina);
            return propinaTotal;
    },
    propina2(){
        var prop2=0;
        //propina por porcentaje
        var porcentaje2=0;
        //propina directo
        var directo=0;
        //se agarra el porcentaje de la vista
        porcentaje2=this.porcentaje / 100;
        prop2=(this.auxSubTotal)*porcentaje2;
        directo=prop2;
        //Mando una copia del subtotal a la seccion del data 
        //Para el uso de otros calculos
        this.propina3=prop2.toFixed(1);
        return directo;
        
    },
    
    noArticulos(){
        var acum=0;
        for (var i = this.ventas.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            acum=acum+this.ventas[i].cantidad;
        }
        return acum;
    },

    cambio(){
        var camb=0;
        camb=this.pagara_con - this.granTotal;
        camb=camb.toFixed();

        return camb;

    },
    filtroProducto:function(){
            return this.productos.filter((sku)=>{
                return sku.nombre.toLowerCase().match(this.buscar.toLowerCase().trim()) 

            });
        },
        filtroGuias:function(){
            return this.guias.filter((id)=>{
                return id.nombre.toLowerCase().match(this.buscar.toLowerCase().trim()) 

            });
        },
},


}) 
} window.onload = init;
```

y este es el codigo  fuente de la libreria FPDF que estoy usando actualmente

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default configuration for FPDF
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the default values for creating a PDF with FPDF
    |
    */

    'orientation'       => 'P',
    'unit'              => 'mm',
    'size'              => 'A4',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | With Laravel Vapor hosting
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If the application is to be hosted in the Laravel Vapor hosting platform,
    | a special header needs to be attached to each download response.
    |
    */
    'useVaporHeaders'  => env('FPDF_VAPOR_HEADERS', false),

];
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar como invocas al cuadro de dialogo, y una captura de como es ese cuadro de dialogo?

Comment: ya lo puse @EvilFearzZ

Comment: Ya entiendo, lo que quieres es mandarlo directamente a la impresora. Este tutorial está en español y puede ayudarte. necesitas saber tu red local y el nombre de tu impresora, así como su ip. saludos. https://sistemasumma.com/2012/01/28/impresion-automatica-de-tiquet-con-fpdf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, feliz tarde, yo trabaje en una empresa donde tenian software de punto de venta y lo que haciamos era un truco en el navegador para cuando se mande imprimir, este mande de una vez y no salga el cuadro de dialogo, la verdad lo hice muchas veces y me funciono, te dejo el enlace que te explica paso a paso como hacerlo con el navegador firefox, https://donnierock.com/2020/06/03/configurar-impresion-silenciosa-silent-print-en-firefox/,  creo que es lo que necesitas

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).